Routing issue in nextjs site on S3 and cloudfront
I'm experiencing issues with my Next.js website deployed on AWS CloudFront, where refreshing the page or accessing it directly with a URL without the ".html" extension redirects to the home page instead of the expected page. How to solve this issue?This is my folder structure
This is my next.config.js file
I'm expecting to get the same page even after the refresh. Navigation from menu is working fine, only after refresh it is redirecting to the home page.

The issue you're experiencing is likely related to how CloudFront handles requests and your Next.js routing configuration.

Try adding this to your next config file : trailingSlash: false,
Make sure your CloudFront distrib is correctly configured to handle dynamic routes.
If you're using S3 bucket as the origin, configure a custom error page to handle 404 errors and redirect to your index.html.
If nothing works try using a Lambda@Edge to intercept and rewrite URLs - add it as an origin request lambda function inside your CF behavior -  something like:


exports.handler = async (event) => {
      const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
      const uri = request.uri;
    
      if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
        request.uri = uri + 'index.html';
      } else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
        request.uri = uri + '.html';
      }
    
      return request;
    };





The solution from Meryem worked for me but i just used a Cloudfront function and not an Edge one.
resource "aws_cloudfront_function" "rewrite_request_static" {
  name    = "${var.environment}-req-static"
  runtime = "cloudfront-js-1.0"

  code = <<EOF
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;
    if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
        request.uri += 'index.html';
    } else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
        request.uri += '/index.html';
    }
    return request;
}
EOF

  comment = "Rewrite all paths to /index.html"
}

Then i did the association part in the cloudfront dist in Terraform too..
